# How to fix missing files or folder error: File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 110, in tf.app.run()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, tensorflow-datasets

When I execute the following command I get the below error from Tensorflow "missing file or folder". I've checked all online solutions for this error, but nothing is resolving my error.

`python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record`

**The error:**

> ```
>     File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 110, in 
>     tf.app.run()
>     File "C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
>     _sys.exit(main(argv))
>     File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in main
>     tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
>     File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 56, in create_tf_example
>     encoded_jpg = fid.read()
>     File "C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
>     self._preread_check()
>     File "C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
>     compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
>     File "C:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowc\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in exit
>     c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>     tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\tensorflowc\models\research\object_detection\images\train\tr1138a1a1_3_lar : The system cannot find the file specified.
>     ; No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: What solutions did you try and did not work? Do note some research models don't support Windows OS. See https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2215#issuecomment-426370761

Comment: I'm using tensorflow for face detection. [link](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem

If you are making a `.CSV file` using an `xml_to_csv file.py`,

You have to check the file extensions such as .jpg, .png, and .jpeg in the `train_labels.csv` file.

In my case, the extension names are not there!

[image]

**Solution:**

add the extensions like below example and run the following command:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py 
    --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv 
    --image_dir=images\train 
    --output_path=train.record
```

It will work!

Answer (score 2):

My csv-file contained imagenames with jpg extension and I still had this error OP posted. I tried solving it with:

```
python3 generate_tf_record.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv --output_path=train.record

python3 generate_tf_record.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv --output_path=test.record
```

All images were in one folder and flags as shown below:

```
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '','data/train_labels.csv')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path','', 'train.record')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'images')
```

The problem was resolved when I copied the saved record file from the main folder to the data folder.

Answer (score 0):

i was running into the same issue, and no amount of checking the file path (relative or absolute) was working for me. my directory was organized to have images files and xmls in the same folder. the problem came down to the return statement of the split function inside generate_tfrecord.py not having a file extension after the filename it is looking at:

```
def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]
```

**IF** your train and test folders contain images and xmls in the same folder, i would recommend making this edit to the generate_tfrecord.py file:

```
def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename + '.jpg', gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]
```

only after making this edit did the script run for me successfully.